# ¿Cómo añadir un botón a un Navigation Drawer Activity?

Tags: java, android-studio

esta es la primera vez que utilizo un Navigation Drawer Activity y estoy intentando añadir un botón dentro de uno de los fragments de esta para lanzar un intent del fragment de esta activity a otra nueva, el problema es que no se muy bien donde colocar el evento onClick, ¿alguien podría ayudarme?

A continuación les paso mi activity por si alquien puede echarle un vistazo y ayudarme:

```
private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;
private ActivityMain3Binding binding;
private Button boton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    binding = ActivityMain3Binding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    boton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_slideshow);
    setContentView(binding.getRoot());
    setSupportActionBar(binding.appBarMain.toolbar);
    binding.appBarMain.fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
    boton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity3.this, MainActivity4.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    DrawerLayout drawer = binding.drawerLayout;
    NavigationView navigationView = binding.navView;
    mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
            R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow)
            .setOpenableLayout(drawer)
            .build();
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main);
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_activity3, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main);
    return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
            || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
}
```

Muchas gracia por su ayuda.

Comment: Hola. Si el botón va en el Fragment, el listener del mismo debes ponerlo también en el Fragment. NavigationDrawer no tiene nada que ver aquí, éste se usa para el menú lateral que habitualmente cargarías en la actividad principal.

Comment: @A.Cedano tiene toda la razón. Estoy haciendo una aplicación que tiene drawer y lo confirmo.

Comment: Si, lo acabo de probar y sin problema, muchas gracias